# Validate a path against a json schema

Tags: json

I am using com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema

A sample schema look like below:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "address": {
       "type": "object",
       "properties": {
         "city": {
            "type": "string"
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Now I have to validate in java code:

```
address.city -> valid path in json
address.pincode -> invalid path
```

I have tried the below approaches and both does not seem to be a good one:

1. Manually iterate through the schema
2. Generate a dummy payload and then validate the path. However, in actual schema I do have custom types as well and generating the dummy payload seems to be an overkill for this task.

Comment: To clarify, are you given `address.city` and you have to verify that it represents a location in the schema (which is basically just JSON data for your need)?  Or are you wanting to verify that `address.city` represents a location in the data that the schema would validate?

Comment: Hello, How these two are different? address.city represents a location in schema as well as in data. However, I do not have data in hand but just the schema and I want to validate the location against the schema.

Comment: `address.city` does _not_ represent a valid location within the schema.  The value in the schema under `address` doesn't contain a property named `city`; it contains `type` and `properties`.